# Automatically suspend 18.04.1 at idle login screen

Tags: gnome, login, suspend, login-screen

This PC is often left in a logged out state at the login screen. I have set power options to automatically suspend on idle, and these do work if a user is logged in.

They do not work if the computer is left at the login screen though. Using gdm3 as the login.

How can I enable this?

Comment: Came here searching for the solution, but on 19.04.  Hopefully another comment gives this a bump?

Answer (score 0):

This thread might contain your solution:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2425058&p=13881017#post13881017

> First, I needed to use su to switch to user "gdm":
>
> `sudo su - gdm -s /bin/bash`
>
> (If running in a non-GUI context, such as ssh, I also needed to run :
>   `export $(dbus-launch)` )
>
> Then I was able to set some gnome settings as the the user "gdm"
>
> `GSETTINGS_BACKEND=dconf gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type suspend`
>
> `GSETTINGS_BACKEND=dconf gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 120`
>
> This sets the GDM3 screen to suspend after 2 minutes idle. Verify the
>   settings with "get" commands:
>
> `GSETTINGS_BACKEND=dconf gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type`
>
> `GSETTINGS_BACKEND=dconf gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout`
>
> These values can also be modified with GUI dconf-editor. Before the su
>   command, you need to run (as your regular user)
>
> `xhost +`
>
> and then after the change to gdm user via su, you can run:
>
> `dconf-editor`
>
> Be careful, though, with using this app.